# How do I setup default routes that match just parameters?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

This is how I want my routes to work:

```
http://example.com               -> UpdatesController.Query()
http://example.com/myapp/1.0.0.0 -> UpdatesController.Fetch("myapp", "1.0.0.0")
http://example.com/myapp/1.0.0.1 -> UpdatesController.Fetch("myapp", "1.0.0.1")    
http://example.com/other/2.0.0.0 -> UpdatesController.Fetch("other", "2.0.0.0")
```

My controller looks like this:

```
public class UpdatesController : Controller {

    public ActionResult Query() { ... }
    public ActionResult Fetch(string name, string version) { ... }

}
```

The route config that I've tried is this:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Fetch",
    url: "{name}/{version}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Updates", action = "Fetch" },
    constraints: new { name = @"^.+$", version = @"^\d+(?:\.\d+){1,3}$" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Query",
    url: "",
    defaults: new { controller = "Updates", action = "Query" }
);
```

But only the first example works. The others that should call the `Fetch` action method all fail with 404.

What am I doing wrong?

(I've also tried it without the route constraints, but there is no difference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add following code to web.config, because your url contains **dot value (1.0.0.0)**

```
<system.webServer>
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

**Another way**

you can do it via Attribute routing.

to enable attribute routing, write below code in RouteConfig.cs

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

In controller your Action look like this

```
[Route("")]
public ActionResult Query()
{
 return View();
}

[Route("{name}/{version}")]
public ActionResult Fetch(string name, string version)
{
 return View();
}
```